# How to bulk load thousands of json files to elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, load

I know there are many other places where I can find different answers to my problem, but i have tried most of them without resolving anything.

I am trying to index 85.000 JSON files to my elasticsearch instance. 
The JSON files are small, 99% less than 2 Kb, and are created by onionscan, which is a tool aimed at crawling dark web sites in order to get informations (emails, bitcoin addresses, etc) and identify vulnerabilities.

I have been able to index 90% of my files, but the remaining 10% (which is the most important part, because only that 10% of Json files contain information!), does not get loaded.

Currently, I am using this code, which is able to load only the JSONs where the Onionscan crawler has not found anything:

```
    import requests, json, os
    from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

    directory = 'C:/Users/Hp/onionscan_results'

    res = requests.get('http://localhost:9200')
    print ("Loading JSON objects to Elasticsearch. Please wait...")
    es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': '9200'}])

    i = 1

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".json"):
         f = open(filename)
         docket_content = f.read()
            # Send the data into es
         es.index(index='darkweb', ignore=400, doc_type='docket', id=i, 
     body=json.loads(docket_content))
         i = i + 1
```

This is a JSON sample from my repo:

```
     {  
       "hiddenService":"qnzsbipihn3coe63.onion",
       "dateScanned":"2019-04-17T20:57:16.185098805Z",
       "online":false,
       "performedScans":[  
          "web"
       ],
       "webDetected":true,
       "crawls":{  
          "http://qnzsbipihn3coe63.onion/":3575956962652378467,
       },
       "pgpKeys":null,
       "certificates":null,
       "bitcoinServices":{  
          "bitcoin":{  
             "detected":false,
          },
          "bitcoin_test":{  
             "detected":false,
          },
          "litecoin":{  
             "detected":false,
             "userAgent":"",
             "prototocolVersion":0,
             "onionPeers":null
          }
       },
       "sshKey":"",
       "identifierReport":{  
          "privateKeyDetected":false,
          "foundApacheModStatus":false,
       },
       "simpleReport":{  
          "hiddenService":"qnzsbipihn3coe63.onion",
          "risks":null
       }
    }
```

I do not get any error message while trying with the above code. It just quits, but then the total number of indexed JSONs in Elasticsearch is not what i expect (roughly 10.000 do not get indexed). I have also tryed with Curl with no success (maybe I do not know the exact command).

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: I just realized this is a JSON issue. The JSONs are valid, but some of them cannot be indexed by ES due to something i do not understand. I now get an error log but it is very, very long and confused. How can I submit it?

Comment: How is your index configured? Analyze the documents that are not being indexed and check their fields' data types with index mappings. Also, bulk request should respond with indexing errors for each document.